# How come I still got resources in clan wars when I didn't get a star

Tags: clash-of-clans

We just had clan wars and I'm th9 I attacked there number 1 who is th 11. I got no stars at all but still got 260k gold and elixer and 1.4k dark. I asked my clan but no one seems to know why this is. I only got 36% as my pekka and King went on a mission of there own.

Comment: Did you use both attacks in the war?

Comment: Yes my first attack I got 143k gold and elixer

Comment: There number 1 was supposed to be 686k gold and elixer. We also won the war

Comment: Are you sure it just wasn't old starbonus? It sounds like you are in master 2, and you got a starbonus

Answer (score 2):

When you attack TH higher than your's, then you get a percentage of the available loot. When you attack TH equal to lower to your's, then you have to get atleast 1 * to get the loot.

Answer (score 0):

You get some percent of bonus loot even if you just try an attack, it seems. How much you get depends on your clan level and the win bonus on the enemy base, I suppose.